# Step function in Gymnasium Framework for Atari games yields game_over() error

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

I try to load and run an atari game for reinforcement learning in python Gymnasium.
Whenever the env.step(action) function is called it yields the following error

My code was

```
game_name = 'VideoPinball-v0'
env = wrap_env(gym.make(game_name,
                        render_mode="rgb_array"))
env.reset()

print("Observation Space: ", env.observation_space)
print("Action Space       ", env.action_space)


for _ in range(1000):
  action = env.action_space.sample()
  obs, reward, terminated, truncated, info = env.step(action)

  if terminated:
    observation, info = env.reset()
env.close()
```

and the result:

> TypeError: game_over(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
>
> 1. (self: ale_py._ale_py.ALEInterface) -> bool
>
> Invoked with: <ale_py._ale_py.ALEInterface object at 0x7f7d821dde70>; kwargs: with_truncation=False

however it is not clear to me what the root problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I was using ale-py 0.75 which was causing the error in combination with gymnasium==0.27.1.
upgrading to 0.80 fixed the problem.